# Loading Data from local MySQL server into Phonegap application

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, cordova

I'm trying to connect a MySQL server to my phonegap application. I currently have a localhost MySQL and Apache Server running on XAMPP. Here is my PHP script that I am using to call a simple SELECT statement on my server:

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$port=3306;
$socket="";
$user="root";
$password="";
$dbname="mydb";

$con = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname, $port, $socket)
    or die ('Could not connect to the database server' . mysqli_connect_error());

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$array = $result->fetch_row($result); 

echo json_encode($array);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Next, I make an jQuery JSON call within my javascript in order to obtain the information and simply print it out on my page.

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'js/users.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            var id = data[0];              
            var fName = data[1];
            var lName = data[2];

            $('#output').html("<b>id: </b>"+id+"<b> first name: </b>"+fname+"<b> last name: </b>"+lname);
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    });
```

Yet whenever I attempt to run this code, the ajax call errors out and my browser returns a Status:200 and statusText:OK.

I would really appreciate any help on this matter. Thanks!

Comment: Where is your page that containing the ajax call? You probably did write the right path... Try using the full url localhost:/.../.../user.php to see if that works or try writing that `url: <?=__DIR__?>'/js/users.php'` assuming that you are using php5.3 or higher

Comment: The ajax call was made within my javascript index.js. I changed my code to use the full url to the users.php call and it still returned the same error message.

Comment: Where is the location of the php file that are including the index.js. Does the folder js is in the same folder of your php page that is using index.js

Comment: The location of the php file is located in 'localhost:8000/browser/www/js/users.php'. Yes, it is in the same folder as my index.js script.

Comment: But the one that is using index.js does it is in www/ ?

Comment: That is correct, my index.html is in www/

Comment: You seam to have the good path.. I dont know :s

Comment: What happens when you open js/users.php with your browser? Can you post us the json you get?

Comment: When I open the users.php in my Chrome browser, it simply downloads the php file.

Comment: You first need to separate the server code from the app code. So, you create your cordova app, it will contain a www folder, you put your app html, css and javascript there (the .js that makes the ajax call). Then you put your .php on a server folder. Finally, on the $.ajax url you use the absolute server url, using the server IP instead of localhost

Comment: Thank you, jcesarmobile! Your answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jcesarmobile, I was able to figure out my problem. You cannot store your .php scripts within your project's directory.